# ALTER Table and add intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data and structure:

```
Date       Analyst      Start Time   Stop Time
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   7:00         10:00
```

I need to expand the start time and stop time to be broken down into 30 minute intervals.  The final table should look as follows:

```
Date       Analyst      Start Time   Stop Time
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   7:00         7:30
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   7:30         8:00
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   8:00         8:30
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   8:30         9:00
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   9:00         9:30
4/2/2018   Bill Smith   9:30         10:00
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using MySQL within a query?

Comment: Not with a query, but you can do it in a stored procedure. Is that an option?

Comment: Yes...I could do a stored procedure.  Are you able to provide any insight on the stored procedure or point me to some documentation that would help in my quest?

Comment: You can google it. The question is too broad for SO. If you face some issues while writing the stored procedure, you can come back and post your code for help.

Answer (score 0):

I did this stored procedure for you, the only thing you can improve is merge all results in one (if it's possible).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
DECLARE vFecIni DATETIME;
DECLARE vFecFin DATETIME;
SET vFecIni = CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' ', '00:00:00');
SET vFecFin = CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' ', '00:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    WHILE vFecIni < vFecFin DO
        SELECT vFecIni;
        SET vFecIni = vFecIni + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggests this is quite a broad topic, however it is still possible to set you off on the path to accomplish this task since you sound like you are up for the challenge.

Break it down into stages.

First, you'll need a table to work with (tableB) which will allow you to write the newly created timeslot records. This should match the schema of the existing table (tableA). It's simpler, and safer, to write to a second table than complicate matters with a mixture of updates and inserts if you try to work only with the existing tableA.

Second, define the procedure. The basic structure of the example cursor in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) is perfect for your needs once you strip out all the references to cur2 and the `IF b < c THEN ... END IF;` block.

You should follow the exact structure of the example and start by declaring variables for each of the columns in tableA. The declaration for cur1 should select all the columns from tableA. You will need to process the rows returned by the cursor within the LOOP, as in the example, but for this you'll need to define a WHILE ... END WHILE block. If you called your variables vDate, vAnalyst, vStartTime and vStopTime then the WHILE block would look something like this:

```
WHILE vStartTime < vStopTime DO
  INSERT INTO tableB (`date`,`analyst`,`startTime`,`stopTime`) 
    VALUES (vDate,vAnalyst,vStartTime, ADDTIME(vStartTime, '00:30:00'));
  SET vStartTime := ADDTIME(vStartTime, '00:30:00'); 
END WHILE;
```

CALL the procedure and you should populate tableB with the timeslot records you require.

Finally, when you are happy with the definition and records in tableB, drop tableA and rename tableB to tableA.